# table [X] has no column named [Y]

Tags: android-studio, base-de-datos, android-sqlite

Estoy intentando crear un usuario en android studio, cuando presiono el boton de registrar usuario, me lanza un error:

```
E/SQLiteLog: (1) table Usuario has no column named ap
E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting ap=prueba usuario=prueba nombre=primera pass=prueba1
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table Usuario has no column named ap (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO Usuario(ap,usuario,nombre,pass) VALUES (?,?,?,?)
```

Este es el metodo que cree para insertar el usuario:

[image: Aqui se ve que es lo que hace segun el debugger]

Dejare la tabla:

```
String tabla="create table if not exists Usuario (id integer primary key autoincrement, usuario text, pass text, nombre text, ap text)";
```

aqui el metodo InsertarUsuario:

```
    public boolean InsertUsuario(usuario u){
        if (buscar(u.getUsuario())==0){
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put("usuario", u.getUsuario());
            cv.put("pass", u.getPassword());
            cv.put("nombre", u.getNombre());
            cv.put("ap", u.getApellido());
            return (sql.insert("Usuario", null, cv)>0);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
```

```
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "usuario{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", Usuario='" + Usuario + '\'' +
                ", Password='" + Password + '\'' +
                ", Nombre='" + Nombre + '\'' +
                ", Apellido='" + Apellido + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
```

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: El campo ap, ¿Lo creaste en conjunto con la tabla o creaste la tabla, instalaste la app y luego creaste el campo ap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error indica:

> table Usuario has no column named ap

En idioma español:

> El usuario de la tabla no tiene una columna llamada ap

Indica que tratas de realizar una inserción a un campo `ap` que no existe:

```
INSERT INTO Usuario(ap,usuario,nombre,pass) VALUES (?,?,?,?)
```

en tu tabla, aunque el script para crear la tabla es correcto y contiene este campo:

> String tabla="create table if not exists Usuario (id integer primary
> key autoincrement, usuario text, pass text, nombre text, ap text)";

El problema se debe generalmente a que se creo una tabla la cual no contiene este campo, te sugiero eliminar caché de la aplicación o incluso eliminarla y volver a instalarla, esto provocará que se cree la estructura correcta de la tabla la cual incluira el campo `ap`.

Comment: Gracias, si debia desinstalar la app, ya me funciono.

Comment: Excelente @MELVINANTONIOSALGUERO en ocasiones sucede que subimos una estructura diferente y como no se vuelve a construir nos indica que hay campos que no existen.